# php mysqli query if i add sum or count it doenst work

Tags: php, mysqli

how do i count punten for each band_naw in php en so the result?
i have three dropdowns the first band you select is 3 punten second 2 punten and the third is 1 punten.

**here is my code:**

```
/* Change database details according to your database */
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'popgroep');

$query  = "SELECT band_naw, SUM(punten) AS punten FROM `resultaat` ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo "<ul>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<li>{$row['band_naw']} {$row['punten']}</li>";

    }

    echo "</ul>";

} else {

    echo "Query didn't return any result";

}
```

my table

[image]

error said that column punten not exist but that its strange because i made it

thanks for the comments

Comment: If instead of retuning a useless error message in your `else` you actually returned the `mysqli_error($dbConnection)` it would have told you that the query was failing and **more importantly WHY** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want relative sumarization, you need to group your data with GROUP BY

```
SELECT band_naw, SUM(punten) AS punten FROM resultaat GROUP BY band_naw
```

Comment: Still not work it said that the column punten not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT band_naw, SUM(punten) AS punten FROM band GROUP BY band_naw";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<li>".$row['band_naw']." ".$row['punten']."</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
else
{
    echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: Still not work it said that  the column punten not exist

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE `resultaat`. execute this query in your database and post your table schema.